# What is a ball as in meat ball?

Tags: vocabulary, cibus

There are various foods that are called "balls" in English, perhaps most famously "meat balls".
What would be a good Latin word for a ball in this sense?
I can think of words for a ball in general, but there is no guarantee that any of them is applicable here.

Comment: At all events avoid *botulus.*

Comment: ...because of botulism, food poisoning from bad tinned beans.  What did you think I meant?

Comment: @Hugh That was one thing, but L&S does also mention a vulgar secondary meaning which does align with "sausage". I was not sure which one you meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not *globus* or *globulus*? Each is a word that basically means a spherical mass. The former has a wide range of uses, and would be a reasonable choice, but for 'meat ball' I should prefer the diminutive.

Comment: The [MSFUL](https://ia801000.us.archive.org/12/items/TheLexiconAnglumEtLatinumByDavidMorgan/MorganAndSilvaFurmanUniversityLexicon.pdf) gives _colyphium_ and _globulus carneus_ as translations of meat ball, so I think _globulus_ is probably a good answer.

Comment: Building off your answer and @Hugh comment: botulus globuli sounds beautiful

Comment: @tox123 I'm not sure I follow. What would you use *botulus globuli* for? Sounds like a sausage filled with meatballs or some such thing. For just "ball" I would choose *globulus*. The word *botulus* has a vulgar meaning beside "sausage", which can make it a little awkward for culinary use. (Also, the @-ping doesn't work unless you comment under the same post.)

Comment: @joonas Ilmavirta I think that tox123 meant to write _bubuli_, which would probably serve (it's derived from _bos_).

Comment: @TomCotton Ah, that would make perfect sense! It never crossed my mind, as I am not all that familiar with the word *bubulus*.